# FOR/F two consecutives delims

Tags: batch-file

I have the following FOR /F loop in a batch file in windows 7:

```
   set name=ROSSI-PAOLO-15012016--ROME-15012017-VIA ROMA--ITALIA--
   for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=-" %%a in ("%Name%") do (
   echo %%a, %%b, %%c, %%d , %%e )
```

I need that the parameter nb. 4 , that is equal to the variable %%d , could be set to null and not set to the following parameter.
This happens because there are two delims (hypens) in the string.
Is it possible to have the following result ?
      %%a=ROSSI
      %%b=PAOLO
      %%c=15012016
      %%d=
      %%e=ROME

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
@echo off

set name=ROSSI-PAOLO-15012016--ROME-15012017-VIA ROMA--ITALIA--
   for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=-" %%a in ("%Name:--=- -%") do (
   echo %%a, %%b, %%c, %%d , %%e
)
```

This will replace `--` with `- -` which will set space on the place of the double delimiter and the corresponding token will be space.